# Validate dynamic php form with javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, php

I've tried the following code for javascript validation. When the form is submitted, only the first input field is validated. How could I validate all the dynamic values of the form?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function validate() {
                if (document.f.phone.value.length == "0") {
                    alert("Phone is required");
                    document.f.phone.focus();
                    return false;
                } else if (document.f.file.value.length == "0") {
                    alert("file is required ");
                    document.f.file.focus();
                    return false;
                } 
                
                return true;
            }   
        </script>

<?php

    echo '<form name="f" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return validate();">
           <input type="text" name="phone[]" class="required">
           <input type="file" name="file[]" class="required">
           
           <input type="button" class="add" value="add"/>
           <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" class="Submit">    
    ';
    
?>
```

Comment: Try `document.f.file.files` instead of `document.f.file.value`.

Comment: you have defined your form elements like `file[]` and `phone[]` you need to access them like  `document.f.elements['phone[]'].value` and  `document.f.elements['file[]'].value`

Answer (score 1):

if i understood correctly then you want to validate dynamic value in the form. instead of writing logic to validate the fields just add the `required` keyword to the fields which you want to make mandatory. that should save you extra effort of writing validation. go for custom validation when inbuilt validation are not enough

```html
<form name="f" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="text" name="phone[]" required class="required">
  <input type="file" name="file[]" required class="required">

  <input type="button" class="add" value="add" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" class="Submit">
```